# How can I make these images same size using bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

**Q1**
I was wondering how I could make all the images the same size using bootstrap? In addition, how would I adjust it to my needs if I wanted it smaller or bigger?

**Q2**
How can I make these images `img-responsive`?

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <a href="https://codemoji.com/blog/Coding.jpg" target="_blank">
              <img src="https://codemoji.com/blog/Coding.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%">
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <a href="http://i1126.photobucket.com/albums/l611/ldocherty1/IMG_0730_zpsiz4dqc47.jpg" target="_blank">
              <img src="http://i1126.photobucket.com/albums/l611/ldocherty1/IMG_0730_zpsiz4dqc47.jpg" alt="Nature" style="width:100%">
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <a href="http://www.discdepotdundee.co.uk/files/2014/07/intel-and-amd-processor-installation-disc-depot-dundee.jpg" target="_blank">
              <img src="http://www.discdepotdundee.co.uk/files/2014/07/intel-and-amd-processor-installation-disc-depot-dundee.jpg" alt="Fjords" style="width:100%">
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To make the images same size set `min-height` to the images.
2. To make them smaller or bigger change the responsive classes `class="col-md-4 col-sm-4"`. they are responsible for the width.
3. To use `img-responsive` class just add `class="img-responsive"` to the `img` tag.

**Working Snippet**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <a href="https://codemoji.com/blog/Coding.jpg" target="_blank">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="https://codemoji.com/blog/Coding.jpg" alt="Lights" style="min-height:400px;width:100%;">
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <a href="http://i1126.photobucket.com/albums/l611/ldocherty1/IMG_0730_zpsiz4dqc47.jpg" target="_blank">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i1126.photobucket.com/albums/l611/ldocherty1/IMG_0730_zpsiz4dqc47.jpg" alt="Nature" style="min-height:400px;  width:100%;">
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <a href="http://www.discdepotdundee.co.uk/files/2014/07/intel-and-amd-processor-installation-disc-depot-dundee.jpg" target="_blank">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.discdepotdundee.co.uk/files/2014/07/intel-and-amd-processor-installation-disc-depot-dundee.jpg" alt="Fjords" style="min-height:400px; width:100%;">
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer!

Comment: glad that it helped.

Comment: If you wouldn't mind assisting me further how can I align up the images with the paragraph boxes below? In addition, I tried making all the images the same size as the third image above the future goals box. However, when I change the dimensions the outline box doesn't adjust. https://jsfiddle.net/bLp7fd9e/15/ (Don't forget to open the website view up to full)

Comment: or this can be done to make all them same height https://jsfiddle.net/bLp7fd9e/19/

Comment: Cheers much appreciate. Lastly, In your jsfiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/bLp7fd9e/19/ how can I remove the blank box space under the text? Furthermore, how can I align up the images and <p> boxes with the `jumbotron text-center container`? Once again thanks for the help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139084/discussion-between-sfvfsvsvvvsvvf-and-neophyte).

Answer (score 0):

- You can try setting a fixed value to height value, a value that adjust to all your images.
- You can play setting a fixed value to widht and `height:auto` or fixed height and `width:auto`
- To do this without modifying css you need adjust your images dimension and then you can use *img-responsive* because this class have this css styles:
  `display: block;`
  `max-width: 100%;`
  `display: block`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback. I've tried using the third option. However, I can't seem to get it working. Do you mind editing my code with the answer please? Or should I show you my example which you wanted to correct it?

Comment: in external css file you can add (examples): 1- `.thumbnail img{height: 300px}` 2- `.thumbnail img{width: 300px; height: auto}` or `.thumbnail img{width: auto; height: 300px}` 3- suppose that you adjust your images to 1600x1200, then just add `img-responsive` class. There are many form to do this, also you can use media queries to adjust width or height